# How to draw chessboards in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, chess, skak

I wonder which module you can use to draw chessboards in ConTeXt.
When I was using LaTeX, `skak` is fine but now I a bit stuck.

In LaTeX the code looks like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
    \newgame
    \mainline{1.b4 b6} \\
    \showboard
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a chess module for context (and I certainly don't plain to write one).

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, there isn't any package dedicated to chess. Depending on what you want, you can actually piggyback on `skak`:

```
\usemodule[filter]

\defineexternalfilter
    [chess]
    [filter=pdflatex,
     output=\externalfilterbasefile.pdf,
     readcommand=\readPDFfile,
     purge=no,
     bufferbefore=chessbefore,
     bufferafter=chessafter,
    ]

\def\readPDFfile#1{\externalfigure[#1]}

\startbuffer[chessbefore]
  \documentclass{minimal}
  \usepackage{skak}
  \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{preview}
  \newgame
  \hidemoves{
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[chessafter]
  }
  \showboard
  \end{preview}
  \end{document}
\stopbuffer

\starttext
\startchess
  1. b4 b6
\stopchess

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: wow, context using latex to get something working ;-). But I guess it wouldn't work in a context standalone, or can context find an existing texlive? Btw: you are missing the rank numbers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Not sure why the rank numbers got cropped. Either `preview` package in LaTeX or `\startTEXpage` in ConTeXt is being too aggressive. Regarding context standalone finding texlive, that depends on the path. One can pass a `PATH` setup to the filter command (at least on linux) to make sure everything works. Even without munging with the path, simply calling pdflatex usually works as long as pdflatex does not call a binary that is provided by context standalone (e.g., bibtex).

Comment: the number are cropped as they are not inside the bounding box. You need to setup some border (this would be easier with chessboard, it has keys for this).